# Schema location even number of URI's on marshaling

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I am using the [following schema](http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.1/graphml-structure.xsd) to parse [GraphML XML](http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/) files.

I managed to bind java classes from the schema (using xjc) and also unmarshaled a few example XML files.

Unfortunately, when I come to marshaling the XMLs I am getting the following error:

> SchemaLocation: schemaLocation value = 'Graphml.xsd' must have even number of URI's

As far as I can see the only schemaLocation use in the xsd is the following:

```
<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"                
  schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/xlink.xsd">
  ...
```

But I can't see a problem in it.

Can someone suggest what is wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The schema fragment you show is syntactically correct; you are right not to find any problem there.  The error message also doesn't seem to be talking about the schema at `http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.1/graphml-structure.xsd` -- it's talking about something called GraphML.xsd.

Without seeing the XML instance it's hard to be sure, but perhaps in the document instance there is an attribute value specification of the form `xsi:schemaLocation = "GraphML.xsd"` and a validator is complaining that the value "GraphML.xsd" needs instead to be a value containing an even number of URIs:  namespace-name, schema-location pairs (as described in Blaise Doughan's answer).

Answer (score 4):

There are two parts to a `schemaLocation` the first is the namespace and the second followed by a space is the location. Something like the following would be valid.

```
<foo 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0 http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/xlink.xsd">
    ...
</foo>
```

A schema location can be set on a `Marshaller`.  Is it possible that you are doing the following?

```
Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION, "Graphml.xsd");
```

Comment: Thank you! The problem was that the schema location property was incorrectly filled in the marshaller.